# nav bar dropdown not work any thoughts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

basically I used the demo and I am sure all the js are loaded correctly .... really need help.
The button just cannot toggle
Following are my JS and css

```
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/static/css/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="/static/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>


  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

`

Comment: please provide HTML/CSS/JS code or a http://jsfiddle.net/ for us to help.

Comment: please edit your above post with any CSS you used

Comment: we need your css @AngryPandaChi

Comment: all my css and js are directly from view-source:http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/#

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lcue3x07/1/ - looks fine

Comment: Proper spacing and separation in contents